# How to add vue (vuetify) to existing php application

Tags: php, vue.js, vuetify.js

We would like to add vue (or some UI framework base on it) to our existing php application.

I know there are many articles and official documentation, how to install it, but it is most for new projects.

Has anybody good tutorial, how work with it comprehensively? Eg. with routing, comunication with PHP, rights management, building for production with vue cli... .

Comment: Are you using laravel by any chances ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Petr! We can't say if anybody has a tutorial which would be considered good from your perspective, and Stack Overflow is not a good website to ask about such things as they are opinionated and won't lead to good Q&A based on facts. There are certainly tremendous resources available, but for asking about your case I'd recommend a concrete programming question and first of all browse the existing Q&A if you can already find a direction. I've picked one Q&A to close against, to not otherwise close vote your question as off-topic so you get a better start.